# What happens when a market-maker goes bankrupt during / as a result of an over-extended unsupported position?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, shorting-securities, market-making

The [meme stocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme_stock) have me thinking about the exchange backend. What happens when a market-maker / money-maker has an extreme position in a stock that is now unsupported by shares, just derivatives and loans on short positions and during a long drawn-out fight with retail is bankrupt during the squeeze to eventually cover their position? How might that affect the retail shareholders who legitimately sell with million + profits per holder? How do the brokerages of the retail shareholders get the money to cover the settling positions in retail?

With billions of potential losses, no rescue loans, the investment market-maker would liquidate their other positions, pushing the overall market down quickly to help cover, but what then? The market dumps, the market maker goes bankrupt, the meme stock rises... will the retail shareholders accounts settle with the profits or?

Comment: Just curious... Has anyone ever heard of the market dumping because a market maker got into trouble due to a long drawn out fight with retail?  Market makers can hedge.  With the meme stocks, it was the hedge funds who were shorting who were pushed to the brink.

Comment: @BobBaerker And if those fail, who owes the lent shares back to the retail investors?

Comment: If you are referring to shorted shares, that has nothing to do with the market maker.  The borrower of the shares (the shorter) owes the shares to the lender.

Comment: Short is a different concept than what a market maker is capable of with naked shorting and synthetic shares.

Comment: Short is a different concept than what a market maker is capable of with naked shorting and synthetic shares. Looking at what is happening reminds me of the tranches in the RE crash. It will be the lowest levels here in the meme stock craze that fail. HF’s short. Then naked short by selling. The Market makers get involved as it obvious by the pattern in all stocks since February related to the meme’s. Then add in the dark pool OTC trades and it makes it obvious market makers are now involved more than the HF’s who started it. So, what happens when the naked short then shorted against naked?

Comment: Who ends up paying if companies bankrupt and bring down the market as the liquidate? Has anything close ever happened even in another market in modern times?

Comment: Based on the move by Goldman on Friday, buffers are being established to avoid bk but it is in fact bringing the market down.